# What is the Avalonia data binding equivalent to `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`?

Tags: data-binding, avalonia

How do I set `, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on a xaml `{Binding}` in Avalonia? When I try, compilation fails with:

> System.Xaml.XamlException: 'Unable to resolve suitable regular or attached property UpdateSourceTrigger on type Avalonia.Markup.Xaml:Avalonia.Markup.Xaml.MarkupExtensions.ReflectionBindingExtension Line 91, position 100.' Line number '91' and line position '100'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always PropertyChanged. I.e., other options are not supported.
See https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/3754

Comment: This doesn't appear to be true within a `DataGridTextColumn`, where the view model's property doesn't get set until the cell loses focus. Any suggestions there? I found switching to `DataGridTemplateColumn` and using a `TextBox` manually gave me the behavior I want.

Comment: We have bindings refactoring going on in progress, which planned to include UpdateSourceTrigger as well.
But DataGrid is such an old control (ported from Silverlight), that it parses bindings by itself anyway, and processes them in its own way. Can you create an issue for this DataGrid scenario, so it won't be missed?

Comment: Thanks for that. Filed https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/13533